# How to install vsftpd package

Tags: rhel, yum, vsftpd

I am having a rhel6 server i want to install vsftpd package from there to my client machine
How to do this.

Comment: `yum install vsftpd` .. you can setup local yum repo using CD , just do google search

Comment: I tried `yum install vsftpd` but it is not finding the package

Comment: RHEL required RHN register to use yum.. so you have to set up local yum or download rpm packages and install it manually.

Comment: You can always get the CentOS vsftpd RPMs and install them too.

Comment: You can actually just mount the DVD and install the RPM's from there. You run into RPM hell though so you're better off setting up the DVD as a repo like Rahul suggested. Here's a tutorial for it that I found online: http://tharindu.info/2011/05/06/adding-dvd-as-base-repository-in-rhel-6/

Comment: Ultimately, though, I'd look into whether you really want to use RHEL or if CentOS is the better fit. If you're dealing with an existing system I guess that's one thing, but if this is a new install, I'd seriously recommend reinstalling with CentOS. RHEL is almost pointless without a subscription, all you get is the ability to install an OS. If software QA is that important to you and that's why you're using RHEL instead, then you need to buy a subscription so you get bugfixes/can submit feature requests. If it's not then CentOS should serve you at the level you need it to.

Answer (score 3):

To install using **YUM** Your RHEL should Register with RHN or You can setup Local Yum repository for the same.

If you are installing from the CD-ROM:

1. mount the CD-ROM: `mount /dev/cdrom  /mnt/`
2. change to the RPMS directory in the CD-ROM: `cd /mnt/RedHat/RPMS`
3. if you know the name of the package type ls  packagename*  (e.g. `ls *vsftp*`) to find the full package name
4. if you don't then type  ls  and look for it. I rather suggest you read the packages list and find its name there and do as in item 3 above.
5. type   `rpm  -ivh  filename.rpm` to install a new package.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't registered your RHEL install to be able to use RedHat's repositories, you can download the rpm from an online repo and use:

`yum localinstall filename.rpm`

I prefer this to `rpm -ivh` because if you end up with a repo in the future, yum will already be aware of your package (vsftp in this case) and be able to update it if necessary withouy complaining that the yum database was modified outside of yum. FYI

Comment: Since vsftpd don't have dependices.. it can be install using rpm